# Gutenberg editor in WordPress 5.0.3 /wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4713/autosaves?_locale=user 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: plugins, updates, block-editor

I recently upgraded WordPress from 4.3 version to 5.0.3 version.

Now I am trying to add following code in to a page of a WordPress site in the Gutenberg editor.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "xyz",
    formId: "abc",
    sfdcCampaignId: "pqr"
});
</script>
```

I get following error in the console

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4713/autosaves?_locale=user 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried following to fix it.

1. Updated and saved permalinks  : did not work
2. Checked WordPress logs        : no error messages, only some notices
3. No specific errors in the error logs

As of now I have installed classic editor plugin and it allow to save this script.

How to fix this issue with Block editor

Comment: What is `js.hsforms.net`? Is it related to a WordPress plugin?

Comment: @PatJ  js.hsforms.net is to add hubspot forms

Comment: As far as I know I don't think you can by default.  You could create your own custom block to allow adding scripts, or use a plugin to do so.  You could also take out this code and add it in footer.php with a page conditional.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis ok, but if I add same to the classic editor it works.

Comment: The classic editor and the new block editor are very much different.